# How to accelerate numerial inverse laplace transform for pdes of Euler-Bernoulli beam problem

Tags: differential-equations, performance-tuning, numerics, integral-transforms

Happy new year! :) Recently, I am practicing laplace transform technique for solving pdes.

In [this extemely helpful post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127980/dynamic-euler-bernoulli-beam-equation), @xzczd mentioned that "The last step is to transform the solution back, but sadly InverseLaplaceTransform can't handle tsol.".

So, I tried to numerically do inervese laplace transfrom using both built in command `InversLaplaceTransform` and external package `GWR` command, but the code is so slow. Also, the result seems not correct when comparing the answer therein.

So, where is the problem. Am i using command wrong? Below is my code. Thanks.

```
Remove["Global`*"] // Quiet;
<< NumericalLaplaceInversion.m;

(*LaplaceTransform[x'[t],t,s]*)
(*s LaplaceTransform[x[t],t,s]-x[0]*)

f[x_] = x (1 - x);

pde = D[u[t, x], {t, 2}] + D[u[t, x], {x, 4}] == 0;
ic = {u[0, x] == f@x, Derivative[1, 0][u][0, x] == 0};
bc = {u[t, 0] == 0, u[t, 1] == 0, Derivative[0, 2][u][t, 0] == 0, 
   Derivative[0, 2][u][t, 1] == 0};
odeUgly = LaplaceTransform[{pde, bc}, t, s] /. Rule @@@ ic;
ode = odeUgly /. 
    HoldPattern@LaplaceTransform[a_[t, x_], __] :> a[s, x] // 
   Flatten;
(*s is a parameter, not a variable, no its derivatives
u[s,x]===U[x]
*)
odesol = u[s, x] /. First@DSolve[ode, u[s, x], x] // Simplify;
(*odesol=DSolveValue[ode,u[s,x],x]//Simplify*)

uatx[x_] = Function[s, odesol // Evaluate];
(*uatx[z]*)

(*usolGWR[ti_,xi_]:=GWR[uatx[xi//Rationalize],ti]//Chop;
datGWR=Table[{x,usolGWR[0.2,x]},{x,$MachineEpsilon,1,0.1}]
ListLinePlot[datGWR,PlotRange\[Rule]{{0,1},{-0.3,0.3}},Mesh->All]*)

usol[ti_, xi_] := 
  InverseLaplaceTransform[uatx[Rationalize@xi][s], s, N@ti] // Chop;
dat = Table[{x, usol[0.2, x]}, {x, 0, 1, 0.1}] // Quiet;
ListLinePlot[dat, PlotRange -> {{0 - 0.01, 1 + 0.01}, {-0.3, 0.3}}, 
 Mesh -> All]
```

Comment: The `DSolveValue[……]` line is wrong. After transforming `teqn` is actually an BVP of ODE, so it should be `DSolveValue[……, x]`. But after the correction `DSolveValue` returns unevaluated at least in v12.3.1 (undoubtedly a bug), so, use `DSolve` instead.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Sorry for the silly mistake. I have learned so much from you in this forum. I corrected the code and everything seems to be right now. However, the speed is still low, is it possilbe to accelerate it? How about the compile trick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that the automatic method choosing of `InverseLaplaceTransform` isn't working well, at least in *v12.3.1*. Let's test the speed of the available methods:

```
AbsoluteTiming@
   InverseLaplaceTransform[uatx[0.2][s], s, 0.1, Method -> #] & /@ {"Stehfest", 
  "Piessens", "Talbot", "Durbin", "Crump", "Papoulis", "Weeks"}
(*
{{8.25883,   0.0760733 + 5.4345*10^-17 I}, 
 {0.501488,  0.0758119 - 1.91165*10^-15 I}, 
 {0.0237084, 0.075812}, 
 {0.47879,   0.0743344}, 
 {0.134007,  0.0846437}, 
 {0.132482,  0.100495 - 0.000824042 I}, 
 {5.25566,   0.0760956}}
 *)
```

Hmm, `"Talbot"` method looks like a much better choice, let's turn to it:

```
usol[ti_, xi_] := InverseLaplaceTransform[uatx[xi][s], s, N[ti], Method -> "Talbot"]

ListLinePlot[Table[usol[0.2, x], {x, 1/10^8, 1, 0.01}], 
  DataRange -> {10^-3, 1}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]